# What is the difference between before_action and prepend_before_action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My codebase contains callbacks like 
`prepend_before_action :authenticate_api_user!` and
`before_action :authenticate_api_v1_user!`
What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Generally `before_action` runs `before every action` to a `method` and
`prepend_before_action` does what it says. It just add your definition at index zero.

Here is a great use case to prove the same:

```
class ConfuseUsersController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_action :find_user, only: [:update]
  prepend_before_action :new_user, only: [:create]

  before_action :save_and_render

  def update
  end

  def create
  end

  private

  def find_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new_user
    @user = User.new
  end

  def save_and_render
    persited = @user.persited?

    @user.assign_attributes(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect users_path(@user)
    else
      render (persited ? :edit : :new)
    end
  end
end
```

- `before_action :save_and_render` this makes `save_and_render` to get called before every action.
- `prepend_before_action :find_user, only: [:update]` This prepends `find_user` function to get called before `save_and_render`

Another example:

We have an `ApplicationController` where...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :one
  before_action :three
end
```

Now in any controller if we want to execute any other method for e.g. `two` before `three` you can use  `prepend_before_action` like
`prepend_before_action :three, :two`

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_action :three, :two
end
```

Now before `three` gets executed `two` will get `execute` and then `three` for this specific method.

Comment: I've been trying to call a method with before_action for sessions#create and in my terminal I can see it happening after the create method.  I finally tried prepend_before_action and now the method runs before my create method.